# Sorting within a cell in a list specifically by each character in the cell

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I am working on an application in which I have a C# list of a type that I defined myself and it has about 7 columns and several rows of data. In particular I have a column `Term` of type string which usually contain alpha-numeric items.

Sample data

```
Time      Product Term    Strike  Strategy  Premium  Volume
8:52:00     LN  F15-H15     350     PUT     0.106   100
8:33:29     LN  V14         400     CALL    0.033   100
9:42:51     LN  X14-J14     425     CALL    0.059   100
10:14:14    LN  X15-V15     325     PUT     0.1325  25
12:11:23    LN  H15 vs X14  450     CS      0.229   1000
12:12:03    LN  H15 vs X14  450     CS      0.229   550
12:12:58    LN  J14 vs F14  450     CS      0.229   100
12:13:33    LN  H15 vs X14  450     CS      0.229   100
12:14:20    LN  X14 vs H15  450     CS     0.229    100
```

As seen in the above list I have a column named Term and I am trying to performing sorting within each Cell which has symbol `"-" (hyphen)` and `"vs"` in the cell like sorting them numerically and alphabetically for example in the third row of Term Column I have `X14-J14` but I wanted it to be sorted alphabetically and make it `J14-X14` as the numbers are both same but in case where numbers are different then it should be sorted by giving number the higher priority like `H15 vs X14` should be sorted as `X14 vs H15` making the lower number to come first irrespective of the alphabet.

Resultant data is to be stored in a list and should look like

```
    Time      Product   Term       Strike  Strategy Premium  Volume
    8:52:00     LN  F15-H15         350     PUT     0.106   100
    8:33:29     LN  V14             400     CALL    0.033   100
    9:42:51     LN  J14-X14         425     CALL    0.059   100
    10:14:14    LN  V15-X15         325     PUT     0.1325  25
    12:11:23    LN  X14 vs H15      450     CS      0.229   1000
    12:12:03    LN  X14 vs H15      450     CS      0.229   550
    12:12:58    LN  F14 vs J14      450     CS      0.229   100
    12:13:33    LN  X14 vs H15      450     CS      0.229   100
    12:14:20    LN  X14 vs H15      450     CS      0.229   100
```

**Is there a good way I could solve this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do this. There is going to be string manipulations, and plenty of them:

```
public string SortTerm(string term) {
    Match match = Regex.Match(term, @"([a-z]\d{2})(-| vs )([a-z]\d{2})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (match.Success) {
        string left = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string mid = match.Groups[2].Value;
        string right = match.Groups[3].Value;

        int a = int.Parse(left.Substring(1));
        int b = int.Parse(right.Substring(1));

        if (a > b || (a == b && left[0] > right[0]))
            return right + mid + left;
    }

    return term;
}
```

In short, if the `term` string doesn't match the pattern you described, return it unchanged. Otherwise, swap the order if the right-side is less than the left.

This will respect the type of separator string ("-" or " vs ").

## Usage

You can use this on collections in a number of ways.

If you have your objects stored in a `List<T>`:

```
values.ForEach(val => val.Term = SortTerm(val.Term));
```

If you have an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
foreach (var value in values)
    value.Term = SortTerm(value.Term);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are comparing numbers too which has higher priority

Comment: Yes. The `if (a > b || ...)` accomplishes that. If _a_ (left side) is larger, swap. Otherwise, if _a_ and _b_ are equal then compare the letter.

Comment: Will the above affect the performance at which it runs because the above code is just for one string if I have to run it for entire list do I need to loop it?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the method as it is defined above in a loop. I will provide some examples.

Comment: What if one of the term is like J17-V17 vs J18-V18

Comment: The method will return that value unchanged, since it doesn't match the regex pattern. Making the pattern matching work recursively will require some effort, depending on how much you have to allow. For instance, could a valid term look like "J17 vs V17 vs J18-V18", or must the separator strings be symmetric?

Comment: I would say symmetric it would only be J17-V17 vs J18-V18 and it also cannot contain 2 "vs" in the string. Overall there would be five types one J17,V17,J17-V17, J18 vs V18 and J17-V17 vs J18-V18. Please also note that number of characters on either side of "vs"(if any) would be equal

Comment: Anyways, I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this if you can use LINQ

```cs
var list =  new [] { new {Term="F15-H15"}, new {Term="V14"}, new{Term="X14-J14"}, new{Term="X15-V15"}, new{Term="H15 vs X14"}, new {Term="H15 vs X14"}, new {Term="J14 vs F14"}, new {Term="H15 vs X14"}, new {Term="X14 vs H15"} };

var sorted = list.Select(x => x.Term.Split(new [] {"-", " vs "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).OrderBy(s => s).OrderBy(s => s.Substring(1, 2)).Aggregate((c, n) => c + "-" + n));
```

NOTE: it does not preserve the separator -, vs